# Calculating vectors with the cosine law (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

I was trying to develop a little console aplication for solving additions between vectors using the Cosine Law:

```
sum = sqrt((s1 ** 2) + (s2 ** 2) + (2 * s1 * s2 * cos(angle)))
print(sum)
```

`# Where s1 and s2 are the sizes of the vectors, respectively.`

But the, the cos in the equation returned a weird value (the angle was 60, so the `cos(angle)` should be 1/2, right?).

Also, I tried changing the `cos` with `acos` after reading other solutions, but it returned `ValueError: math domain error`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: python's trig functions use radians, not degrees https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the sign before the last term in the cosine law is minus?

Comment: as a comment to the math domain error, `acos` is the inverse of `cos` and can only take values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's trigonometric functions use radians, rather than degrees.  Fortunately, the `math` module includes a function to perform the conversion for you:

```
from math import cos, radians

sum = sqrt((s1 ** 2) + (s2 ** 2) + (2 * s1 * s2 * cos(radians(angle))))
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument of cos() should be expressed in radians.

Comment: so can I just use the `degrees()` function from the math module?

Comment: @user6180500 no, `angle_in_radians= math.radians(angle_in_degrees)`